# Image alignment issues in Wocommerce

Tags: caching, woocommerce, plugins

we are working on flatsome. the image alignment is not proper. Whenever I deactivate wp-rocket plugin, images fixes itself up.

I am not able to understand what is the causing this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors in the console? Also, are you using the "Delay JavaScript Execution" feature in the wp-rocket plugin? If yes, then check the wp-rocket article
https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/1560-delay-javascript-execution-compatibility-exclusions#plugins, It may help you to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi, yes I was able to fix this. The issue here was, there is an option of optimize CSS delivery in wp-rocket. It has two options.

1. remove unused css(beta)
2. load css asynchronously

We have selected remove unused css earlier, I changed it to load css asynchronously and it fixed itself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).